# "Мое мнение – ...." Что поставить: двоеточие или тире?

Tags: пунктуация, тире-или-двоеточие

Как будет правильнее:
"Мое мнение – видеорегистратор достоин 9 баллов из 10."
или
"Мое мнение: видеорегистратор достоин 9 баллов из 10."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сказал по-другому:

*По моему мнению, видеорегистратор достоин девяти баллов из десяти*.
**Или:** *Я считаю, что видеорегистратор достоин девяти баллов из десяти*.

В Вашей же формулировке предложение невозможно нормально произнести, и даже сложно его назвать предложением.

Answer (score 1):

Возможны оба варианта. Выбор зависит от того, является это простым изложением мнения (двоеточие и интонация с понижением тона перед паузой) или это подчёркнутое, эмоциональное противопоставление уже высказанному (или просто возможному) иному мнению (тире; в устной форме - повышение тона перед паузой).

Answer (score 0):

Здесь напрашивается "что", а оно, как правило, заменяется тире. Например: "Не подлежит сомнению — они знали об этом".